# How to implement the clock-signal requirements for the MAX291EPA+ with an Arduino Nano Every?

Tags: arduino, clock, low-pass

The following text is an excerpt from the datasheet for the [MAX291EPA+](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX291_MAX296-1513033.pdf) an 8th-Order, Lowpass, Switched-Capacitor Filter.

> The MAX291/MAX292/MAX295/MAX296 maximum recommended clock frequency is
> 2.5MHz, producing a cutoff frequency of 25kHz for the MAX291/MAX292 and 50kHz for the MAX295/MAX296. The CLK pin can be driven by an
> external clock or by the internal oscillator with an external
> capacitor. For external clock applications, the clock circuitry has
> been designed to interface with +5V CMOS logic. Drive the CLK pin with
> a CMOS gate powered from 0V and +5V when using either a single +5V
> supply or dual +5V supplies. The MAX291/MAX292/MAX295/MAX296 supply
> current increases slightly (<3%) with increasing clock frequency over
> the clock range 100kHz to 1MHz. Varying the rate of an external clock
> will dynamically adjust the corner frequency of the filter.
>
> Ideally, the MAX291/MAX292/MAX295/MAX296 should be clocked
> symmetrically (50% duty cycle). MAX291/ MAX292/MAX295/MAX296 can be
> operated with clock asymmetry of up to 60/40% (or 40/60%) if the clock
> remains HIGH and LOW for at least 200ns. For example, if the part has
> a maximum clock rate of 2.5MHz, then the clock should be high for at
> least 200ns, and low for at least 200ns.
>
> When using the internal oscillator, the capacitance (COSC) from CLK to
> ground determines the oscillator frequency. The stray capacitance at
> CLK should be minimized because it will affect the internal oscillator
> frequency.

Questions:

1. If I go with an external clock is there a pin on the Arduino that would satisfy the requirements?
2. If I go with the internal oscillator, what size capacitor do I need and would it just go between the CLK pin and GND?
3. Which way is better?

Comment: One of the timers of the Arduino can be configured to output an appropriate clock signal. Read the datasheet. You'll have to operate the timer in PWM mode with 50% duty cycle.

Comment: The datasheet is fairly simple. Can you provide more direction on how to configure the timer?

Comment: @TimCerka you'll want to use a library that just allows you to set the period (and potentially duty cycle) of the PWM/timer unit your Arduino (that can be a very large range of very different chips; arduino is more a description of an operating system type) carries.

Comment: @TimCerka I mean the datasheet of the microcontroller that you're actually using.

Comment: I get that Jonathan.